# Flutter: How can I change the Alignment of a Text in a Textfield programmatically via buttons?

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and trying to build some basic text editing options like in word. That means, bold, italic, underlined and so on...

I am currently struggling building those three buttons for left, centered and right text alignment.
I´ve tried to build them the same way as I did with bold and so one;

```
bool isBold = false;
```

Button:

```
_NoteButton(Icons.format_bold, Colors.green, () => setState(() => isBold = !isBold)),
```

In the TextField:

```
style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: isBold ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal),
```

the problem I have is that i only have "one" TextAlignment line for three Alignments, so it´s not possible to do it exactly the same way as with bold or italic.

It would really help if you could share your code of three buttons to align the text on the left, in the center and on the right in a textfield.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable,

```
TextAlign _align;
```

Then use three buttons in a row,

```
Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _align = TextAlign.left;
          });
        },
        child: Text('Align left'),
      ),
      FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _align = TextAlign.center;
          });
        },
        child: Text('Align center'),
      ),
      FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _align = TextAlign.right;
          });
        },
        child: Text('Align right'),
      ),
    ],
  );
```

Then in your `Text` widget,

```
Text('Align right', textAlign: _align)
```